# Sql composite index on 2 datetime fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table called: BookedCars which has StartDate, EndDate and CustomerId as columns.

The query that needs to be super performant just selects all the bookedcars and takes into account STartDate and EndDate aswell as customerId.

```
Select * from BookedCars where GetDate() between StartDate and EndDate and CustomerId = 3
```

Kinda like this.

Would it be okay from a performance point of view to create a CLUSTERERED composite ( yes clustered) primary key index on StartDate,EndDate and then customerId in that order.So it would be composed out of those 3 columns.

I understand the order matters, is my order ok?

I am using SQL SERVER 2016.

I have several mil rows thats why i need to make it as fast as possible.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The column with the equality predicate should be the first column.

There's no point including both `StartDate` and `EndDate` as key columns.

You will only get a seek on either `StartDate <= GetDate()` or `EndDate >= GetDate()` the other part of the `BETWEEN` will be evaluated as a residual predicate.

Likely the second of those options will be better to avoid the seek returning all the historic bookings for the customer.

So the best key column order will be

```
CustomerId, EndDate
```

Whether this should be the clustered index or not depends on your overall query workload including priorities of the query within it.

Making it the CI means the index will be automatically covering so will avoid any lookups to evaluate the residual predicate on `StartDate` and to return the rest of the columns. So it will be optimal for this specific query.

However this will likely be less optimal for inserts (which will encounter more page splits than using a monotonically increasing key) and an effect of this is greater fragmentation (the negative effects of which again depend on the situation).

Comment: very interesting, would be nice to include a brief explanation for residual predicate :P

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem.  Assuming that a given customer only has one record, you can do:

```
Select top 1 t.*
From t
Where customerid = 3 and 
      Getdate() >= startdate
Order by startdate asc
```

If you know there is a batch, this is probably sufficient.  If not, put this in a sub query and add the check for the end date in the outer query.

For this, you want an index on:

```
Customerid, startdate
```

And then perhaps end date.  A clustered index is probably overkill.

Comment: That top 1 is a very impressive optimization no doubt, but why would  a clustered index be overkill? Just have them on the disk sorted in such a way so it fits the way i query them.

Comment: @Aflred . . . A clustered index could definitely work, but it can have a big performance impact on `insert`s and `update`s.